# Where is glibmmconfig.h in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libxml2, glibmm

I have `sudo apt-get install glibmm*` and it shows I have installed all the libraries about it. But when I link it with `libxml++-2.6`, it shows no `glibmmconfig.h`. I have searched Google, somebody says it is in `/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include`, but the path does not exist. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `glibmmconfig.h` is part of package `libglibmm-2.4-dev` and will be installed in one of the following locations depending on your architecture:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include/glibmmconfig.h
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include/glibmmconfig.h
```

To get a list of compiler flags needed to compile code using `libxml++2.6`, run:

```
pkg-config --cflags libxml++-2.6
```

To get a list of link flags, run

```
pkg-config --libs libxml++-2.6
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. I finally found it in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include/glibmmconfig.h`. Why doesn't the package put the files in a regular way?